# xmlrpc how to check for errors

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I am trying to post to wordpress with XMLRPC using this tutorial:http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/xml-rpc-in-wordpress/

the problem is that tutorial does not have any kind of check for errors while post and I am wondering how to check if the post was posted without any problem based on that tutorial.

Maybe someone could help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your response ? in most of cases if its workable xmlrpc server it wil return you a **faultCode** and **faultString**. You also can setup your oun XMLRPC server (see xmlrpc.php **wp_xmlrpc_server_class** filter hook) to debug requests on a server side.